# Потенциальная проблемма в Servlet

Tags: java, servlet

Помогите найти потециальный источник проблеммы в коде, и если он есть подксжите пожалуйста решение?

```
    public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)

            throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        List<User> users = DataProvider.getUsers();

        for (User user : users)
        {

            resp.getOutputStream().println(user.getLastName());

            ...

        }

    }

}

public class DataProvider
{

    private static List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    public static void addUser(User u)
    {

        users.add(u);

    }

    public static List<User> getUsers()
    {

        return users;

    }

}
```

Comment: список пользователей не потокобезопасный

Comment: Подскажите как должен выглядеть потокобезопасный список пользователей?

Comment: Вариантов много. Как вариант - использовать CopyOnWriteArrayList вместо ArrayList. Еще вариант, добавить к методам addUser и getUsers ключевое слово synchronized и возвращать в getUsers копию списка. Это всё для безопасной работы именно со списком. Если еще и сами пользователи меняются, то и с ними надо решать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resp.getOutputStream()` может вернуть тебе

Throws:
IllegalStateException - if the getWriter method has been called on this response

IOException - if an input or output exception occurred

поэтому их нужно обрабатывать. 
Также проверь на NULL

user.getLastName() не может null вернуть?